# MySQL hogging memory

Tags: mysql, ram

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server running mysql 5.7 and a handful of webapps. Mysql is using significant memory and forcing swap usage. We've had a few fatal crashes from high memory usage. I'm working on decreasing the memory reqs of the other programs running on this server but I'm curious if mysql is obviously mis-configured in some way.

I ran [mysqltuner.pl](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl), and took some of the recommendations therein.

8 cores, 20GB RAM, 8GB swap

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

> # The MySQL database server configuration file.
>
> [client]
>     port        = 3306
>     socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> [mysqld_safe]
>     socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>     nice            = 0
>
> [mysqld]
>     # * Basic Settings
>     user            = mysql
>     pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>     socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>     port            = 3306
>     basedir         = /usr
>     datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
>     tmpdir          = /tmp
>     lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
>     skip-external-locking
>
> bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
>
> # * Fine Tuning
>     key_buffer_size         = 16M
>     max_allowed_packet      = 256M
>     thread_stack            = 192K
>     thread_cache_size       = 8
>     myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
>
> # * Query Cache Configuration
>     query_cache_size        = 0
>
> # * Logging and Replication
>     log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
>
> expire_logs_days        = 10
>     max_binlog_size   = 100M
>
> # * InnoDB
>     innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
>     innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

Answer (score 0):

The recommendations of your mysql tuner are making the assumption that this is a dedicated mysql server, and that that the server isn't also handling webapps.

You have `innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G` which means that MYSQL will always try and use 10GB of memory if it can, in order to maximize its performance.

If you need more memory for other programs on the server to use, you should *reduce* the innodb_buffer_pool_size, and set it to a lower amount of memory. However keep in mind that this could severely harm the performance of your database.

It's worth mentioning that in production environments, it's generally considered best practice to have the database and the web app programs running on separate servers.